# Enrolling a second major?! Enrolling IN?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-verbs

I heard a sentence: "Enrolling a second major will increase the career option."

But I think it should be enrolling "in" a second major. Am I right? I looked at dictionary examples and I didn't find such a sentence (except with "in").

I heard it in an academic English test, so I don't think they neglected grammar rules. Here is the audio file: https://realpte.com/questionfiles/audio/201529.mp3

I heard it in both American and Australian accents. The above voice is American. This one is Australian: http://rapid1pars.dl1.rapidpars.com/34489/16083175/7t0hnhffzck/enroll.mp3

Comment: Could you clarify BrE or AmE if possible?

Comment: That audio file is wrong. No one skips the on or in. In AmE you enroll in a course and in BrE you enroll on a course.

Answer (score 2):

In the U.S. we do not *enroll* in majors.  We *enroll* in classes/courses that we need to complete in order to graduate from a college in the subject/field we have *majored in*.  You *major* in engineering and *enroll* in engineering classes.  After graduation you can say, *Engineering was my major.  I majored in engineering.*

If you decide math is hard you can later *change your major* to advertising and begin *enrolling* in advertising classes.

You sentence can be better understood -

> **Majoring** in two or more subjects will increase your career options.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK you usually Enrol (BrE spelling) **on** a course

But might specialise **in** a discipline

So you could argue you might 'Enrol **in** a second major' but this isn't very BrE (it might be AmE though)

In the UK the term major (in an academic sense) is different the US. In the UK, Major is the predominant subject of your course, so you would major in politics and minor in french, if you did a Politics and French degree with a focus more on politics than french.

Comment: Either way it's not the case, because in the 2 voice files there's neither "on" nor "in".

Answer (score -1):

You are correct, it should be "enrolling in" (or "on" if you're british).

"Enrolling a second major" sounds like you are inducting a major into the program, which implies the university is hiring military officers.

That said, it should also be "options", not "option", and "the" is inappropriate in this context.  This would be more correct:

"Enrolling in a second major will increase your career options."

(I don't necessarily agree with that statement, though.)

Answer (score -3):

Gramatically correct would be to say "enroll in", but if the sentence comes from an American, then the explanation is that they like to skip some words which they think are obvious.

Comment: I don't think this is the case. I added the explanation to the question.

Comment: What you say has no basis in reality.

Comment: I’m an American, and I would *never* say “enroll a major”. That simply doesn’t sound right, even if I can’t explain why.

Comment: Absolutely not. I'm an American and "enrolling a second major" isn't valid; it sounds like somebody who doesn't speak English well.